# trap error in httpwebresponse

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a httpwebrequest where a post data that goes into a freeze waiting for a response. I want to have this timeout so I can continue looping and ignore the error.

```
 request.Method = "POST"
                        request.ContentLength = data.Length
                        request.ContentType = "application/xml; charset=utf-8"
                        request.Timeout = 20000
 ....

 **Using oResponse As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()**
                            Dim reader As New StreamReader(oResponse.GetResponseStream())
                            responseData = reader.ReadToEnd()
                            reader.Dispose()
                            oResponse.Close()
                        End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [HttpWebRequest.Timeout Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout.aspx).

With this you can get or set the time-out value in milliseconds for the GetResponse  and GetRequestStream  methods.

Comment: that's just the thing..i did set the timeout

Comment: Seems the question was edited after I have answered. Just to understand, so you set the timeout but a WebException is not thrown when the timeout is exceeded?

Comment: Actually thanks for your response, I got it to work now except now I cannot figure out why the error occurs